# parcols background column color not filling on second page

Tags: parcolumns

I'm trying to use the `paracol` package from a overleaf template to make a CV. I can't seem to get the column color to fill on the second page, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Below is an image displaying the issue and the MWE to produce it. After the break between page 1 and 2 only the text on has the color around it where it should be the full column. What should I be do to correct this?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
% a mashup of hipstercv, friggeri and twenty cv
% https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv
% https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv

\documentclass[lighthipster]{simplehipstercv}
% available options are: darkhipster, lighthipster, pastel, allblack, grey, verylight, withoutsidebar
% withoutsidebar
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}




\sffamily

%------------------------------------------------------------------ Variablen

\newlength{\rightcolwidth}
\newlength{\leftcolwidth}
\setlength{\leftcolwidth}{0.23\textwidth}
\setlength{\rightcolwidth}{0.75\textwidth}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{New Simple CV}
\author{\LaTeX{} Ninja}
\date{June 2019}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\section*{} % this is needed.

\complexheader{headercolour}{Malakan}{Malakan}{Curriculum Vitae}{white}{
\infobubble{\faEnvelope}{cvgreen}{white}{anon@gmail.com}
\infobubble{\faPhone}{cvgreen}{white}{555 123456789}

}

%------------------------------------------------

% this has to be here so the paracols starts..
\subsection*{}
\vspace{5em}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1.7cm}
\columnratio{0.24}[0.59]
\begin{paracol}{2}

\paracolbackgroundoptions

% 0.9,0.9,0.9 -- 0.8,0.8,0.8

\footnotesize
{\setasidefontcolour
\flushright

\large

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Section}\\[0.3em]
{\normalsize

\lipsum[2-4]

% \phantom{turn the page}

% \phantom{turn the page}
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\switchcolumn

\small
\section*{Profile}

\lipsum[4-9]

\vfill{} % Whitespace before final footer
}
\end{paracol}

% \vspace*{\fill}
\centering{\textbf{References available upon request.}}

% \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with simplehipstercv.cls, but replacing it with article causes a host of errors.  In particular, you are missing `\usepackage{paracol}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Here is the link to the overleaf template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/simple-hipster-cv/cnpkkjdkyhhw


The package is declaired in simplehipstercv.sty